# Excel Power Query M Formula - Calculate Seniority of Employees

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have PowerQuery table with a "Start Date" column. I added a custom column `Seniority` where I want to measure the time that the employees works for oau organization. I get error when I enter this formula:

```
DateTime.LocalNow() - [StartDate]
```

I want to get to answer for the formula with years only. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function like this - I named it `fnYearsOld`:

```
(StartDate) =>
let
    Today = Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()),
    YearsDiff = Date.Year(Today) - Date.Year(StartDate),
    YearsOld = YearsDiff - (if Date.AddYears(StartDate, YearsDiff) > Today then 1 else 0)
in
    YearsOld
```

Now you can invoke this function in your table:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "Seniority", each fnYearsOld([StartDate]))
```